# Postgres doesn't use index

Tags: postgresql, random, indexing

I am using postgres 9.5 on linux7. Here is the environment:

```
create table t1(c1 int primary key, c2 varchar(100));
```

insert some rows in just created table

```
do $$
begin
for i in 1..12000000 loop
insert into t1 values(i,to_char(i,'9999999'));
end loop;
end $$;
```

Now I want to update c2 column where c1=random value (EXPLAIN show that index is not used).

```
explain update t1 set c2=to_char(4,'9999999') where c1=cast(floor(random()*100000) as int);
                                    QUERY PLAN                                    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Update on t1  (cost=10000000000.00..10000000017.20 rows=1 width=10)
   ->  Seq Scan on t1  (cost=10000000000.00..10000000017.20 rows=1 width=10)
         Filter: (c1 = (floor((random() * '100000'::double precision)))::integer)
(3 rows)
```

Now, if I replace "cast(floor(random()*100000) as int)" with a number (any number) index is used:

```
explain update t1 set c2=to_char(4,'9999999') where c1=12345;
                               QUERY PLAN                                
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Update on t1  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=10)
   ->  Index Scan using t1_pkey on t1  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=10)
         Index Cond: (c1 = 12345)
(3 rows)
```

Questions are:

1. Why in first case (when random() is used) postgres doesn't use index?
2. How can I force Postgres to use index?

Comment: Not relevant for the question, but: the test data generation can be simplified to: `insert into t1 select i,to_char(i,'9999999') from generate_series(1,12000000) i` - most likely that is also going to be faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because *random()* is a *volatile* function (see [PostgreSQL CREATE FUNCTION](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createfunction.html)) which means it should be (re)evaluated per each row.

So you actually aren't updating **one** random row each time (as I understand you wanted) but a **random number of rows** (the number of rows where its own random generated number happens to match its id), which attending probabilities, it will tend to 0.

See it using a lower range for the random generated number:

```
test=# select * from t1 where c1=cast(floor(random()*10) as int);
 c1 | c2
----+----
(0 rows)

test=# select * from t1 where c1=cast(floor(random()*10) as int);
 c1 |    c2
----+----------
  3 |        3
(1 row)

test=# select * from t1 where c1=cast(floor(random()*10) as int);
 c1 |    c2
----+----------
  4 |        4
  9 |        9
(2 rows)

test=# select * from t1 where c1=cast(floor(random()*10) as int);
 c1 |    c2
----+----------
  5 |        5
  8 |        8
(2 rows)
```

If you want to retrieve only one random row, you need, at first, generate a **single** random id to compare against row id.

> **HINT:** You can think that database planner is dumb and always perform sequential scan over all rows and calculates condition expressions one time per each row.
>   Then, under the hood, database planner is much more smart and, if he know that every time he calculate it (in the same transaction) the result will be the same, **then** he calculate it once and perform an index scan.

A tricky (but dirty) solution could be creating your own *random_stable()* function, declaring it as stable even it returns a random generated number.

...This will keep your query as simple as now is. But I think it is a dirty solution because it is **faking** the fact that the function is, in fact, *volatile*.

Then, a better solution (the right one for me) is to write the query in a form that it really generates the number single time.

For example:

```
test=# with foo as (select floor(random()*1000000)::int as bar) select * from t1 join foo on (t1.c1 = foo.bar);
 c1  |    c2    | bar
-----+----------+-----
 929 |      929 | 929
(1 row)
```

...or a subquery solution like that provides @a_horse_with_no_name

**NOTE:** I used *select* queries instead of *update* ones for simplicity and readability, but the case is the same: Simply use the same *where* clause (with the subquery approach: Off course, using which would be a little more tricky...). Then, to check that index is used, you only need to prepend "explain" as you know.

Comment: Hm... "test=# select * from t1 where c1=cast(floor(random()*10) as int);" returns more than 1 row, how is it possible? taken into consideration that C1 is primary key?  (Thank you all for your reply)

Comment: I explained it at top (but maybe I was'nt so clear): the whole expression is evaluated per each row that is (just for this reason) scanned so the query returns each row wich its own randomly generated number happens to match its id. If i were'nt reduced the range of possible random numbers, most of cases, it would returned no rows. By reducing it I increased the chances, for illustration purposes.

Comment: It was difficult but finally I understood :) Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad to know! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why the index isn't used, maybe because of the definition of the random() function. If you use a sub-select for calling the function, then (at least for me with 9.5.3) Postgres uses the index:

```
explain 
update t1 
   set c2=to_char(4,'9999999') 
where c1= (select cast(floor(random()*100000) as int));
```

returns:

```
Update on t1  (cost=0.44..3.45 rows=1 width=10)
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0)
  ->  Index Scan using t1_pkey on t1  (cost=0.43..3.44 rows=1 width=10)
        Index Cond: (c1 = $0)
```